# exercises not rendering properly in sphinx with jupyter-book

Tags: python-sphinx, jupyterbook

I am working with a jupyter book, where I want to include exercises. To the best of my knowledge, I have followed the [documentation](https://ebp-sphinx-exercise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for this type of directive.
First, in my `requirements.txt` file I have added

```
sphinx
sphinx-exercise
```

In the `_config.yml` file I have included the following

```
sphinx:
  config:
    mathjax_path: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js
  extra_extensions:
    - sphinx_exercise
```

Finally, when I try to create an exercise, I write

```
:nonumber:
:class: dropdown

Text of the exercise
```

The result looks OK, but the icon is not what it should be. Instead of a pencil icon, I get a bell.
Can anybody help get the right rendering of this directive?

Comment: https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-exercise/blob/9357fbb3d80836a246ba38093ffd74352e189082/sphinx_exercise/assets/html/exercise.css sets the icon as `\f303`, which is `pencil-alt` in font-awesome 5. The bell is `\f0f3` (see https://fontawesome.com/icons/bell?f=classic&s=regular). Maybe the css got modified somehow?